# How to create short lived Database entries in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to create some notifications that should be short-lived, 1 day or so. So that I can send out those notifications if the user is accessing all notifications today, but not tomorrow.

Suppose someone is creating some post with, I want to send them a notification whenever post upload is successful. But that notification won't matter tomorrow and will create unnecessary confusion.

I considered using `Sidekiq` for the process, in an `after_commit` hook, trigger a `sidekiq` job to run after `18 hrs`, something like:

```
after_commit :trigger_destroyer

private 

def trigger_destroyer
  if notification_type == 'shortlived'
    NotificationDestroyer.perform_in(3.hours.from_now, id)
  end
end
```

Or I can run a cron job that will read created_at, and type of notifications and delete them there.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: I'm not sure that you've clearly explained the problem you're trying to solve.  Have you tried to white board your user story?  Are there more than one type of action which will trigger notifications?  There are many ways to solve a problem.  But none can be recommended until the user story is clearly defined.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to use Redis which lets you set expiry time on data.  But if you want to keep it in SQL, you have to ask whether it is really necessary to delete all the records in the DB right as they expire, or whether your "notification sender job" (assuming you have one) can just ignore old records by comparing timestamps

Comment: @lacostenycoder  Yes, there are supposed to be `n` kind of notifications. Like `comment`, `like`, `follow` and so on.

Comment: @maxpleaner I did try using `Redis` for this, however, the data is supposed to have multiple associations, and it was all making it too messy to handle. Second approach that you have suggested seems doable, however, it'll just keep increasing the table rows. However, that option is the least messy one as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) or Rake task that purges the entire table instead:

```
class NotificationCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    Notification.where('created_at < ?', 30.days.ago).delete_all
  end
end
```

There are various gems that can be used to set up recurring jobs such as[`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever),[`chrono`](https://github.com/plashchynski/crono), [`clockwork`](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) and [`rufus-scheduler`](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). Heroku also has a [built in scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).

This is far more effective then setting up jobs that do this one row at a time and which will pretty much constantly eat up worker processes.

This should be combined with filtering when you display / use the records in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

If you want these notifications displayed when the user visits the site, you don't need to do anything special with Sidekiq, Redis, Cron, etc. All you need to do is load notifications younger than 24 hours and display them.

As an additional task, you could delete any notifications older than 24 hours at the same time, perhaps also deleting notifications you've displayed ... depending on your needs.

However, if these notifications are to be sent directly to the user without them performing an action (loading a page) to trigger the notification, then you'll need to use some kind of scheduling system like Sidekiq.

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaboration on the previous answer.  You probably just want to set up a scope for displaying the notifications to the users, so something like this should work.

```
class Notification
  belongs_to :user

  STALE_DAYS ||= (ENV['STALE_NOTIFICATIONS_PERIOD'].to_i || 30).min
  scope :active { where('created_at > ?', (STALE_DAYS).days.ago) }
  scope :stale { where('created_at <= ?', (STALE_DAYS).days.ago) }

  def to_s
    self.text # or whatever name of notification body field is
  end
end
```

Run this job ever `stale` days.

```
class NotificationCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    Notification.where('created_at < ?', (stale).days.ago).delete_all
  end
end
```

Then in your views you can do something like this:

```
<% @user.notifications.active.each |notification| %>
  <div class="notification">
    <%= notification %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```